# How to Hide one publish target?

Tags: content-editor, publishing-targets

I have added one extra publish target for some reason. I want only admins to see this.This has to be hidden in both the places (publish window and DB switcher) for non admins.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by removing `Read` access to the `Publish Target` for the users.

1. Open the `Security Editor` from `Sitecore menu > Security Tools`.
2. Select the `Everyone` role from the `Roles and users` selector
3. Expand `/sitecore/System/Publishing targets` node
4. Select the option to remove `Inheritance` from the targets you wish to restrict access to.

[image: Security Editor]

The target will now be removed from database switcher and as a Publishing target for your regular users. Any user which is an Administrator will still have these targets available, since admin role ignores all security settings.

If certain roles need to have these targets available, you can grant access to those specific roles by granting "Read" access to them.

Comment: Does this also hides the publishing target from the Publishing Dialog?

Comment: Yes. The publishing targets are just "regular items" in the content tree. If the user does not have read access, the Item Provider will not return them and so they will not be displayed. Make sure you remove inheritance from the Everyone role.

Comment: Great to know :)